# Can you find error in the following program?

Tags: javascript, html

Mainly the error would be in the function but i can't find it.
I'm a newbie in this section so kindly be patient.

```
        <html>
            <head><title>print names</title>
    <script language="javascript">
        function name() 
    {
          var first, middle, last;
          first = document.f1.fname.value;
          middle = document.f1.mname.value;
          last = document.f1.lname.value;
div1.insertAdjacentHTML("AfterEnd", "<h1 style='textalign:center'>My name is " + first + middle + last + "</h1>");
        }

            </head>
            <body bgcolor="9edcba">
            <h1>here we display the name</h1>
            <form name="f1">
            Enter the first name: <input type=text name="fname" size=15>
            <br>
            Enter the middle name: <input type=text name="mname" size=15>
            <br>
            Enter the last name: <input type=text name="lname" size=15>
            <br>
            <div id="div1">
            <input type=button value="click here" onclick="name()">
            </div>
    </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Please provide the error that is being produced and/or a question?

Comment: your quotes are not balanced

Comment: Please be more specific when you ask any question here.In your program what kind of problem you faced? Here i see you forget to close `</form>` tag.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: I cant see the output after entering the names it should print like "My name is firstname middlename lastname"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>print names</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myname()
    //Changed the function to myname as name is reserved
    {
        var first,middle,last;
        first=document.f1.fname.value;
        middle=document.f1.mname.value;
        last=document.f1.lname.value;
        div1.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<h1 align='center'>My name is " + first+ " " + middle + " " +last + "</h1>");
        //Fixed the above code, added correct quotes + spaces + added a closing </h1> tag
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="9edcba">
    <h1>here we display the name</h1>
    <form name="f1">
        Enter the first name: <input type=text name="fname" size=15>
        <br>
        Enter the middle name: <input type=text name="mname" size=15>
        <br>
        Enter the last name: <input type=text name="lname" size=15>
        <br>
        <div id="div1">
            <input type=button value="click here" onclick="myname()">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Change the function name as name() is reserved.
2. Edited the quotes + ADDED closing `</h1>`
3. Added closing form tags.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

change your div1.insert line with the following line
div1.insertAdjacentHTML("AfterEnd","My name is"+first+middle+last);
and change the name of the function to "name1". as "name" can not be used as a function name.

Answer (score 0):

probably too late but you could also do something like this.

- Changed your form elements classes to ID's since they are safer when getting some kind of input and returning it.
- changed `name()` to `myFunction()` since name can't be used as it is reserved.

```html
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
      var mname = document.getElementById("mname");
      var lname = document.getElementById("lname");
      var currentVal = fname.value + " " + mname.value + " " + lname.value;

      div1.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<h1 align='center'>My name is " + currentVal + "</h1>");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="9edcba">
  <h1>here we display the name</h1>
  <form name="f1">
    Enter the first name:
    <input type=text id="fname" size=15>
    <br> Enter the middle name:
    <input type=text id="mname" size=15>
    <br> Enter the last name:
    <input type=text id="lname" size=15>
    <br>
    <div id="div1">
      <input type=button value="click here" onclick="myFunction()">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you are getting a javascript issue try to add alert and check whether the function is called.

check below code this is will resolve your issue. even though you accept the answer.

```
<html>
<head><title>print names</title>
    <script language="javascript">
        function call()
        {

            var first, middle, last;
            first = document.f1.fname.value;

            middle = document.f1.mname.value;

            last = document.f1.lname.value;

            div1.insertAdjacentHTML("AfterEnd", "<h1 style='textalign:center'>My name is " + first + middle + last + "</h1>");
        }
</script>
        </head>
        <body bgcolor="9edcba">
                <h1>here we display the name</h1>
        <form name="f1">
                Enter the first name: <input type=text name="fname" size=15>
                <br>
                Enter the middle name: <input type=text name="mname" size=15>
                <br>
                Enter the last name: <input type=text name="lname" size=15>
                <br>
                <div id="div1">
                <input type=button value="click here" onclick="call()">
                </div>
                </form>
                </body>
                </html>
```